# Rails 4: removing classes (associations) with migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, migration, model-associations

In a rails application I am doing a relatively major refactoring (in a feature branch) which removes (and replaces) several `has many :through` type associations. Since the structure change is relatively major, I do this by looping through all objects in the 'through' class and replacing it with new objects which are then saved. This is much safer (and easier) than raw SQL, although of course slower, but that is a price I'm willing to pay. Roughly the migration looks like this:

```ruby
def up
  create_table :new_through_table ...
  OldThroughTable.find_each do |x|
    # ... data conversion
    NewThroughTable.create(...)
  end
  drop_table :old_through_table
end

def down
  # vice versa
end
```

In the course of this change, I created new classes in `app/models` and the old association classes are now superfluous once the migration is finished, so I delete the class files and the `has_many` and `belongs_to` code lines in the associated classes and commit the result.

However, since the old associated classes are now gone, anybody who pulls my changes is afterwards incapable of running the migration, since the old class files are gone and the old database structure does not map to the new class structure any more.

I could - theoretically - write the migration to not require any class (raw SQL) but this seems cumbersome to me - plus, I'm missing any validations and callbacks that the classes have. I could also just leave the old class files and associations there but I don't really like the idea.

Is there any other clean way of writing such a migration so that it performs reliably in both directions while keeping the code clean?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the class is instantiated on a drop_table? I don't think I've ever had the problem although it has concerned me in the past. 

Create a 'test' table directly on your database (not through your app so there won't be a model defined). Create a migration with "drop_table :test", if it works then you should be good to go.

Comment: It's not the drop_table command, it is the data conversion in the migration which needs to loop through both old and new models. I'm adding an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to put the models, as the migration requires them, into the migration, i.e.

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
  end

  def up
    SomeModel.find_each do |record|
      ...
    end

    drop_table :some_models
  end
end
```

You would need to reproduce any associations or validations you wanted your migration to use. You end up with a bigger migration but you know exactly what model code the migration is using instead of whatever is current at the point that migrations are run.

Comment: That might actually work. I'll try it out ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: It used to be documented - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations